# Invalid handle when using GetWindowTextLengthW inside accessibiity hook

Tags: winapi, rust

I've been trying to figure out why I keep getting an error code of 6, an invalid window handle, when calling `winuser::GetWindowTextLengthW`.  However, when using the CPP equivalent, it seems to work fine.  Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Here's my callback

```rust
unsafe extern "system" fn WinEventProc(
  _hWinEventHook: HWINEVENTHOOK,
  event: DWORD,
  hwnd: HWND,
  idObject: LONG,
  idChild: LONG,
  _dwEventThread: DWORD,
  _dwmsEventTime: DWORD,
) {
  if !hwnd.is_null() && idObject == winuser::OBJID_WINDOW && idChild == winuser::CHILDID_SELF {
    if event != winuser::EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW {
      return;
    }

    if winuser::IsWindow(hwnd) == 0 || winuser::IsWindowVisible(hwnd) == 0 {
      return;
    }

    let e = std::io::Error::last_os_error();
    dbg!(e); // Successfully completed
    let name_length = winuser::GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd);
    let e = std::io::Error::last_os_error(); // here we get an error code of 6
    dbg!(e);

    // Assume we were given an invalid handle or text-less window
    if name_length == 0 {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the CPP code, that doesn't error with an invalid handle

```cpp
void CALLBACK WinEventProc(
    HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,
    DWORD event,
    HWND hwnd,
    LONG idObject,
    LONG idChild,
    DWORD dwEventThread,
    DWORD dwmsEventTime
)
{
    if (hwnd && idObject == OBJID_WINDOW && idChild == CHILDID_SELF) {
        switch (event) {
        case EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW:
            int l = GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd);

            if (!l) {
                auto err = GetLastError();
                std::cout << err << "\n";
                break;
            }
            
            auto* txt = new wchar_t[l + 1];
            if (!GetWindowTextW(hwnd, txt, l + 1)) {
                auto error = GetLastError();
                std::cout << "error " << error << "\n";
            } else {
                auto text = std::wstring(txt);
                std::wcout << text << "\n";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't following the [contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengthw): *"Function failure is indicated by a return value of zero and a `GetLastError` result that is nonzero."* You are evaluating only one of those conditions.

Comment: The C++ code is checking if `GetWindowTextLengthW()` returns 0 before checking `GetLastError()`.  Your Rust code is not doing the same. BTW, your C++ code is leaking the `new[]`'ed memory, you need to add `delete[] txt;` when done using `txt`. And there is no need to convert `txt` to `std::wstring` when passing it to `std::wcout` via `operator<<`, there is an overload available for `wchar_t*` strings.

Comment: In the C++ code, you call `GetWindowTextLength` twice, the first call is to determine whether the call is successful, but in rust you did not check whether the function was called successfully.

Comment: The C++ code isn't correct either. It checks the length against 0 and outputs the error code in case it is. Failure is indicated by both of the following conditions being true: `1` `GetWindowTextLengthW` returning 0, and `2` `GetLastError` returning a non-zero value. This logic is required to distinguish between windows that don't have a window text, and a genuine error to retrieve the length.